# Generating all combinations using brute force in C++

Tags: c++, combinations, brute-force

I have to make a program that generates all possible combinations through use of a brute force approach.

The question is as follows:

Suppose that I have 3 tasks and 2 processes. I will make a 3x2 array and make all possible combinations to assign every task to every process and thus make different combinations. Note that I don't have to create process through fork() or stuff like that; I simply want to show all possible combinations of how 3 tasks can be assigned to 2 process. I have to show every combination. A combination will be, which have all tasks completed through process(es). I will show you some example of how to create combinations.

Note that it is 2d array in table format below. Don't get confused from the example as it can't be displayed in table format here.

e.g-1

```
T1 T2 
T3 -
-  -
```

e.g-2

```
T1 T2 
-  T3
-  -
```

e.g-3

```
T1 - 
T2 -
T3 -
```

e.g-4

```
T2 - 
T1 -
T3 -
```

Hence every possible factor. You can see that an example has all tasks I.E. T1,T2,T3 and none of them is repeated.

Kindly help me to make a c++ program to solve this problem.

The maximum array size can be of 1000x5.

Comment: The STL algorithms have a good function for this type of thing. I'm not sure how well it'd fit into this being homework though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably reading the STL documentation will help you:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Comment: no...it is useful when tasks are equal to no of process....but it may not be the case...actually process represent no positions to be filled and task represent that who will fill them...for e.g if i have 2 process and 5 tasks..then i have 2 positions at a time...so